# Reactive mono how to propagate subscription context to `doOnSubscribe` and `doFinally`

Tags: reactive-programming, aspectj, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have following aspect that tracks method execution time:

```
public Object addMetricsToReactiveMonoTimedMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ReactiveTimed reactiveTimed) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        Mono<?> mono = (Mono<?>) pjp.proceed();
        return mono
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> stopWatch.start())
                .doFinally(signalType -> {
                    stopWatch.stop();
                    logTimer(pjp, stopWatch, reactiveTimed.name(), signalType);
                });
}
```

Method itself looks like that:

```
public Mono<String> sayHi() { 
  return Mono.just("hi")
    .subscriberContext(context -> context.put("requestId", "requestId"));
}
```

How can I get `requestId` variable from subscriber context in my aspect method? I want to use it in `doFinally` to know which request was profiled.

Comment: That is just a killer phrase and thus not very constructive. Why would the fact that AspectJ is blocking be a problem? It runs in the same thread as the intercepted code and merely decorates it with some additional functionality (cross-cutting concern). That is legal. It is up to the developer not do to unnecessary "expensive" (and blocking) stuff in her aspect. If an aspect derails a whole application, it is a problem - with or without reactive programming. Using a powerful tool and not being a "fool with a tool" requires practice, experience and care, like always in this profession.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf where did you get that AOP is blocking? That's not true. There is nothing wrong with using AOP with Reactor. The code in the question is perfectly fine, you can find other examples in resilience4j: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/3362c61758245bc9e0d365fb5a94d73ef1b49679/resilience4j-spring/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/configure/ReactorCircuitBreakerAspectExt.java Please, stop spreading false information...

Comment: @IvanLymar you might try spring-cloud-sleuth library which is used for tracing. It is able to populate the MDC log context based on Reactor context. So you might be able to get request ID in the logs without actually putting that there manually.

Answer (score -1):

*Disclaimer: I have never used Reactor or anything like it in my whole life. I found this question due to the **aspectj** tag.*

After a quick look at the [`Mono` Javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscriberContext-java.util.function.Function-) to me it looks like you could just call `subscriberContext(Function<Context, Context>)` again in the aspect, just like in the target method. You get the existing context as an input parameter for the function or lambda and can do with it what you want. The result of your dummy function/lambda would be a new context, but you can just discard it. I have not tested it, but I mean something like this:

```java
// ...

Mono<?> mono = (Mono<?>) pjp.proceed();

// Alternatively, use a List<Context> with one element, a Stack<Context>, ...
Context[] targetContext = new Context[1];

mono.subscriberContext(context -> {
  targetContext[0] = context;
  // We can also return null, it does not matter because we are not interested
  // in the newly created context, only in the original one we salvaged into the
  // outer array.
  return context;
});

System.out.println("Now do whatever you need to do with " + targetContext[0]);

// ...
```

I use a single-element array/list - instead you could "abuse" any other wrapper object such as an atomic reference or a thread-local as a wrapper because you cannot directly assign a to a `Context` variable from inside the lambda. The code would not compile because the outer variable referenced from inside the lambda needs to be effectively final.

Comment: What was the downvote for? I delivered what the OP asked for. I did not say it was a good idea. Why not feedback about what could be improved in my answer instead?

Comment: A note on the `AtomicReference`: `Context` is defined per `Subscriber`, but it should be noted that `Mono` can be seen as a lazy factory for `Subscription`, whenever a `Subscriber` decides to subscribe to the `Mono`. As a result, storing data in external state like the `AtomicReference` is problematic, since multiple subscribers would "share" the same ref and overwrite it.

Comment: @kriegaex from what I know `threadLocal` should not be used in reactive. And I don't have access for required variables from aspect. Aspect has just pjp, where as variable that I need is http request header.

Comment: @SimonBaslé do you have an idea how to implement it in the way I need?

Comment: there's currently no real way of doing that... only doOnEach allow access to the context, but it doesn't trigger on subscription nor cancellation. you could detect completion and error though

Comment: @SimonBaslé so my real sample is http controller. Each request has `requestId` and I'm using that id to track entire request flow. Using splunk I can select all the logs by that id. I'm propagating that ID through subscriberContext to all my logs. What you are saying is that it's not possible to propagate that ID to the aspect, right?

Comment: Guys, I think you don't get it: `AtomicReference` or `ThreadLocal` are just a cheap trick to easily get wrappers around objects out of a lambda into an outer context. If you don't like it, just write your own `MyCustomWrapper<T>` to which you can assign an object or use an array or collection with a single entry so as to avoid assigning a value to an effectively final object. I never meant those wrappers to be used like normal atomic references or thread-locals. The OP asked how to get access to `Context` from an aspect and I answered the question correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer. It still does the same as before, but does not use `AtomicReference` or `ThreadLocal` anymore. But really, it does not make any difference. Those two were never meant to do anything "thread-ish", just to be containers, as I said. Access your correlation ID from the advice method, then discard the `Context` object again and do **not** pass it through to anywhere else so as not to breach the "reactive contract".

Comment: Now if the `Context` object contains anything useful for you at the time of executing the aspect code, is something I do not know, it is none of my business. I just did what you asked for: Give the aspect access to the context object.